# Distribution of a function of uiform and iid Random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $U,V,W,$ are three independent random variables uniformly distributed in the open interval $(0,1)$. How can we find the distribution of a random variable $Y$ such that $$Y=\frac{1}{U}\sqrt{V^2-2W^2}$$

Any kind of graphical depiction of the  variation  $Y$ is also  appreciated.

Comment: Any attempts on the question?